# C# How to return first letter from a string as a char in a method?

Tags: c#, methods, char, return

I'm making an assignment in my class, which question is:
Create a method, call it `A`, and make it return the first letter in a string.

This is my code:

```
{
    String f = "flying";
    String str = A(f);

    Console.WriteLine(str);

    Console.ReadKey();
}


public static string A(string s) 
{
    string first = s.Substring(0, 1);
    return first;       
}
```

But it's not acceptable, as I'm returning a `string` rather than a `char`. I can't find anywhere how to return the letter 'f' in flying as a `char`, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi Saman, did any of the answers help you to solve your problem? If so you might consider to mark it as accepted. This will help future visitors of this post to see the this thread is closed and has a definite solution to their problem. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help. Have a nice day

Answer (score 12):

basically a string is an array of chars, so if you would treat it like one and access the first position using the [[ ] operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
char c = s[0];
```

You will get a char.

This will of course lead to problems if your string is [either `null` or empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx). So you really should check for that cases:

```
char c = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? : s[0] :  ' ';
```

another possibility would be simply to convert it to a char using the [Convert.ToChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here again a check would be necessary

```
public static char A(string s) 
{
    return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? Convert.ToChar(s.Substring(0, 1)) : ' ';
}
```

Sidenote: If you wonder what the `?` is about have a look on the [?: Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

As pointed out by Ehsan Sajjad using [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) should suffice:

```
return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? s.First() : ' ';
```

Comment: It should be noted its worth checking that there is at least 1 character to send

Comment: @BugFinder thank you, was just writing it down in an edit :)

Comment: isn't `s.First()` enough ? why convert to `Char` array?

Answer (score 2):

You could index a string like an array because it's just an array of chars.

```
public char GetFirstChar(string text)
{
    return text[0];
}
```

But you should keep in mind that this will cause an Exception when you've got a null or empty string. That's why it would good to handle this.
You could use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for this.

This could look like

```
public char GetFirstChar(string text)
{
    var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? ' ' : text[0];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also this function called ToCharArray() you can call on a string. From that array you can just take the first element. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static char A(string s) {
    char[] allChars = s.ToCharArray();
    char first = allChars[0];
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
public static char A(string s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

    return s.DefaultIfEmpty(' ').First();
}
```